# ng-selected not working with select in angularjs

Tags: html, angularjs

I am new to Angularjs.I am trying to set default value for select in angularjs with static values.I am not using any ng-repeat or options.But i am not able to set default value using ng-selected.Everywhere i find solutions only for ng-options but not for static values.

Here is my html

```
    <select name="gender" id="gender" data-ng-model="gender" ng-
    selected=="Male">
    <option value="">Select Gender</option>
    <option value="Male">Male</option>
    <option value="Female">Female</option>
    </select>
```

Can anyone tell where i am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ng-selected directive can be used only in `<option>` tag

Check the below code

```
  <select name="gender" id="gender" data-ng-model="gender" >
    <option value="">Select Gender</option>
    <option ng-selected="true" value="Male">Male</option>
    <option value="Female">Female</option>
    </select>
```

Comment: This is the one i was looking for.Thank you very much :)

Comment: If we use `ng-model` there is no need to use `ng-selected` it works even without it. check my second example in my answer.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `ng-init` directive. As Sraven said , `ng-selected` must use `<option>` tag.

[My Example](https://jsfiddle.net/jackk88888/wnvxW/9/)

```
<select name="gender" id="gender" data-ng-model="gender" ng-init="gender='Male'">
    <option value="">Select Gender</option>
    <option value="Male">Male</option>
    <option value="Female">Female</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Still not selecting

Answer (score 2):

You can set default value for ng-model in controller, try adding this in your controller

```
$scope.gender = 'Male';
```

Comment: It works.But is it not possible with ng-selected then?

Comment: `ng-selected` directive will be used only in `<option>` tag not in <select>

Answer (score 2):

[According to official DOCS](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngSelected), `ng-selected` is for `options` not for `select`.

You should have the `boolean` as `ng-selected` value

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.9/angular.min.js"></script>
<body ng-app="">

<select ng-init="mySel = true">
  <option>Select</option>
  <option value="male" ng-selected="mySel">Male</option>
  <option value="female">Female</option>    
</select>

</body>
</html>
```

**Please check this example using `ng-model`**

The preferred way of doing this is using `ng-model` without `ng-selected`

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.9/angular.min.js"></script>
<body ng-app="myApp" >


<select name="gender" id="gender" ng-model="gender" ng-controller="myCtrl">
    <option value="">Select Gender</option>
    <option  value="Male">Male</option>
    <option value="Female">Female</option>
  </select>




<script>
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
     $scope.gender = "Male" 
});
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: @Sachin Hr, `ng-selected` is for options

Comment: I dont want checkbox.On load only i want to display

Comment: @SachinHR, updated my answer, you can either take `scope` or `ng-init`

Comment: @SachinHR, If we use `ng-model` there is no need to use `ng-selected` it works even without it. check my second example in my answer.